# Angular Dialog not display default

Tags: angular

[image: Modal Image 1]

So I was testing out dialog for angular since I'm learning how to use it and when I tried to run it this happened. Anyone faced this issue before? Didn't get any errors but I'm fair certain this isn't how angular dialogs are supposed to look like. CSS for the modal is also empty but I've messed around to no avail. Unfortunately I'm unable to show the full code as well since it's sensitive.

I'm using
Angular Cli: 11.0.1
Angular Materials: 11.0.0

HTML

```
<p>test-modal works!</p>
```

CSS

```
* {
    background: white;
    color: white;
}
```

Code to call the dialog

```
export class BuyProductComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) { }

  openBuyOnlineModal() {
    this.dialog.open(TestModalComponent, {
      hasBackdrop: false
    });
    console.log('meow');
  }

  closeModal() {
    this.dialog.closeAll
  }

  ngOnInit(): void { }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this in the style.css file :

```
.mat-dialog-container {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

You can also add it in each css file you need it in using  `::ng-deep`

You can also provide dialog height and width in th dialog declaration example:

```
this.dialog.open(DialogComponent, {
  data: {
    //any data
  },
  width: //any width,
  height: //any height
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I came across another issue where my backdrop is constantly white. [link](https://imgur.com/y1ENnny). Do you know a fix for this? I've edited it in the .ts file to hasBackdrop: false but it isn't working either

Comment: Have you tried removing the hasBackdrop attribute completely ?

Comment: Yup, accepted. sorry about that. As for the hasBackdrop attribute, isn't it just a boolean? If it helps I'll post this as a new question as well